# How I restrict in firebase database realtime rules to the users access only their messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This my rules of realtime database, how I restrict in firebase database realtime rules to the users access only their messages?
[image]

Comment: Did you try anything yet? That will give us a better idea of how to help you, instead of  just providing code.

Answer (score 0):

To securely allow access your users access to a subset of data under that node, you need two things:

1. a query that selects only the nodes you want them to access.
2. security rules that then only allow *that* query.

It is important to realize the need for a query here, as security rules in themselves don't filter the data.

So in your case, the query would (in JavaScript) look something like this:

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var query = firebase.database().ref('messages').orderByChild('userId').equalTo(uid);
```

And then you'd validate this query with rules that look something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
                query.orderByChild == 'userId' &&
                query.equalTo == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [query based rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules).